# How to rasterize point data by weighted average in R?

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I have a data.frame of spatial data with crop yields by field. I want to make a heat map by rasterizing this data. I have already been able to produce a map by using raster mean values. I could improve upon this by calculating weighted averages instead, the weight being the plot area. Thus far I haven't been able to make this work.

This is what I've done as a minimal example:

```r
require(dplyr)
require(raster)
require(sf)

d <- data.frame(longitude = runif(100, 10, 30),
                latitude = runif(100, 40, 50),
                yield = runif(100, 2, 6),
                area = runif(100, .1, 10)) %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))

r <- raster(extent(c(min(d$longitude), max(d$longitude),
                     min(d$latitude), max(d$latitude))))

x <- rasterize(d, r, field = "yield", mean)
```

In order to achieve what I need I tried e.g. replacing the last line with:

```r
x <- rasterize(d, r, field = "yield", function(y){weighted.mean(y, w = area)})
```

but that does not work as I thought. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified what you did in creating a reproducible example to avoid getting error. Hope this helps:

```
#require(dplyr) #looks redundant
require(raster)
require(sf)

d <- data.frame(longitude = runif(100, 10, 30),
                latitude = runif(100, 40, 50),
                yield = runif(100, 2, 6),
                area = runif(100, .1, 10)) %>%
                st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))

r <- raster(extent(c(st_bbox(d)))) #modified

x1 <- rasterize(d, r, field = "yield", mean)
x2 <- rasterize(d, r, field = "yield", fun=function(x,...) (sum(x[1]*x[2])/sum(x[2])))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! `dplyr` is indeed redundant. I wasn't aware that `sf` also imports the piping operator. So the indexes in the function argument `x` are the column indexes of the object `d`?

Comment: And thanks also for introducing the `st_bbox` shorthand to me!

Comment: No worries. Yes, the indexes in the function argument `x` are the column indexes of the object `d`. You can now customise your own function, I guess. :)